# How to process data from DataTables Editor in Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm trying to process data sent via DataTables Editor plugin in a Django view.

The received request.POST looks like:

```
{'action': 'edit',
 'data[3115][row1]': 'value1',
 'data[3115][row2]': 'value2',
 'data[3115][row3]': 'value3',
 'data[3115][row4]': 'value4',
 'data[3115][row5]': 'value5'}
```

where 3115 is the primary key of my model.

Whats the intended approach in Django view to get `PK` and `model.row1`, `model.row2`, `model.row3`,... values from the POST data?

The desired output would be something like

```
result = {
    'pk': 3115,
    'row1': 'value1',
    'row2': 'value2',
    'row3': 'value3',
    'row4': 'value4',
    'row5': 'value5'
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: I need something like: `{'pk': 3115, 'row1': value1, 'row2':'value2'...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

a = {'action': 'edit',
     'data[3115][row1]': 'value1',
     'data[3115][row2]': 'value2',
     'data[3115][row3]': 'value3',
     'data[3115][row4]': 'value4',
     'data[3115][row5]': 'value5'}

d = {} # your desired result

for k,v in a.items():
    if k.startswith('data'):
        r = re.match('data\[(\d+)\]\[(\w+\d+)\]$', k)
        if r:
            d['pk'] = r.groups()[0]
            d[r.groups()[1]] = v
```

the `d` will be:

```
{'pk': '3115',
 'row1': 'value1',
 'row2': 'value2',
 'row3': 'value3',
 'row4': 'value4',
 'row5': 'value5'}
```